# "IF" function for analysis of hospital lab frequency

Tags: excel, if-statement, histogram

I work for a hospital that is part of a larger network. We were recently asked by our corporate overlords to address the use of a specific laboratory test. in general, this test should only be performed daily, which should be considered to corresponded to a 24 hour period from last draw. sometimes, however, based on when people arrive to the hospital (e.g. 7pm), and in the interest of bundling labs for a single draw, they may be drawn sooner to coincide with routine testing i.e. 5am. it would never be necessary to otherwise need to repeat within a short (8 hour) window, particularly on the same day.

we have been asked to validate to see if we are adhering to this general practice, as testing any more frequent than that, say, within 12h of a previous test, has no real clinical value and thus adds unnecessary cost.

To address this issue I was given a dataset that among other items includes all instances the lab was performed including collection date and time.

please see HIPPA-safe example below (to be clear, no real data and identifiers are not real); the actual dataset has over 4,174 entries corresponding to 1,328 unique persons. everyone had at least one test performed, not everyone had >1.

I THINK what I want to do is an IF formula that reads the antecedent cell to 1) check if same person and 2) if so, perform a subtraction of the time stamp to display the relevant difference in time, which I can then filter, create histogram, etc. does this seem like a reasonable approach? is there a more preferable method to facilitate analysis? do any other forms of analysis come to mind?

=IF(B2=B1, D2-D1, "n/a")

example data set with formula:
[image: example data set with formula]

Comment: sounds reasonable.  just make sure your data is sorted by column B

Answer (score 0):

> any other forms of analysis come to mind?

By the looks of it you should consider taking the values under "Results" into account, assuming there is a band that might be considered 'normal' readings. The "one in 24 hours is sufficient" rule of thumb may well be appropriate for a series of values within the 'normal' band but not so much so if readings are close to 'danger level'.

That is, in some cases a higher than 'standard' frequency of monitoring may be in the patient's interest, even if not hospital policy, so it may be worth separating the "less than 24 hours interval" readings into those where the higher frequency provided information of little value (eg readings remaining within a 'normal' band) from any that crossed into or out of the band and/or large changes in value. This though may be more a matter of statistical analysis than programming and depend upon whether any action might be taken as a result of such "extra" readings.

Comment: Agree.  The results are an area that would be interesting to evaluate, but at this moment not the main focus of analysis. In general, threshold of interest is 0.50 (more context: the test in question is a procalcitonin assay - systematic review: https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamainternalmedicine/fullarticle/1105880)